# Does there exist a general polynomial for comparing two other polynomials?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given polynomial functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$, does there exist a polynomial function $H(F,G)$ that is yields large values when $F$ and $G$ are close in value and small values when $F$ and $G$ are not close in value.  Here the terms 'large', 'small' and 'close' are left open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$-(F(x)-G(x))^2$$

When $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are close to each other, the value should be a negative value with small magnitude.

When they are far apart, the value should be a negative value with big magnitude.